# Connecting the database without specifying server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

`Database=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;`

Why this connection string works without specifying server /data source. This connected MS SQL SERVER (running in local) from windows app

```
private static string connectionstr = "Database=xxx; User ID=xxx; Password=xxx;"; 
public void connect()
{ 
    scon = new SqlConnection(connectionstr);
    scon.Open();
}
```

Comment: Can you show how do you use it in your code ?

Comment: private static string connectionstr = "Database=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;";
  public void connect(){
           scon = new SqlConnection(connectionstr);scon.Open();}

Comment: it works fine and connected the database without give server/data source, the sql server in local.why?

Comment: See my answer, note its a better to explicitly declare server / datasource as on different platforms you might have issues related to loop-back and more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating `SqlConnection` with a connection string which has no `DataSource` results in a default value which is an empty string ("").

empty string ("") will be translated later to `localhost`, try `ping ""` from `cmd` and see you actually pinging `localhost`.

See [MSDN SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), Remarks section - `DataSource` initial value is `empty string ("")`

Answer (score 0):

The default host name is your localhost.So it will connect your localhost without specifying servername [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @AsishPv If my answer is useful make upvote or mark as useful